# c++ / Elements in a map disapear mysteriously by exiting of a function

Tags: c++, function, class, dictionary, unique-ptr

got a problem in my code with a map, gonna try to explain it the best i can.

My code: (i simplified the code to keep only the parts which cause the problem)

[prog.cpp]

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <fstream>

//this hpp files includes all my other hpp files, i checked the dependencies, all is ok with this
#include "dolmen.hpp"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  //creating a dolmen element
  dolmen::Dolmen DolMen;

  //reading the datas
  std::ifstream trame("trame.txt");
  std::ofstream ofs{"report.csv"};
  std::string dataTxt;

  //std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*> sensorList = dolmen::initialise();
  //std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*> sensorList = std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*>();


  //creating a factory element
  /*using AFactory = dolmen::FactorySensor<std::string, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>, int, std::string>;
  AFactory factory;*/

  //creating a map to store all the sensors
  std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>> sensorList;
  //std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*> sensorList = std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*>();
  dolmen::initialise(sensorList);

  //i'm gonna simplify the call of the method of my sensor
  [grabbing a sensor in my sensor x list]
  x->getID();
  //my x doesn't exists
```

[sensorInit.hpp]

```cpp
#ifndef DOLMEN_SENSOR_INIT_HPP
#define DOLMEN_SENSOR_INIT_HPP 1

/*The DolMen user will only need to modify this file if he needs to add new sensors*/

#include "factorySensor.hpp"
#include "sensor.hpp"
//insert here your sensors hpp files
#include "temperature.hpp"
#include "gyroscope.hpp"
#include "acceleration.hpp"
#include "altitude.hpp"
#include "gps.hpp"
#include "pressure.hpp"

namespace dolmen
{
  //using AFactory = FactorySensor<std::strin    //finding the correct sensor in the sensor list by matching the id with the data frame id
    //dolmen::Sensor* elem;
    std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor> elem;
    if (auto it = sensorList.find(id); it != sensorList.end())
    {
      elem = it->second;
    }

    //searching the maximum number of datas returned by the sensor
    //(some sensors can return one value, some can return many values)
    int max = 0;
    if (elem->getID() == id)
    {
      //decoding the data with the correct sensor, to create a map which contain all the datas of the sensor, from our data frame
      elem->decoding(data);    //finding the correct sensor in the sensor list by matching the id with the data frame id
    //dolmen::Sensor* elem;
    std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor> elem;
    if (auto it = sensorList.find(id); it != sensorList.end())
    {
      elem = it->second;
    }

    //searching the maximum number of datas returned by the sensor
    //(some sensors can return one value, some can return many values)
    int max = 0;
    if (elem->getID() == id)
    {
      //decoding the data with the correct sensor, to create a map which contain all the datas of the sensor, from our data frame
      elem->decoding(data);

      if(abs(int(elem->getValue().size())/elem->getNbAttr()) > max)
      {
        max = int(elem->getValue().size());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "\nsensor not found\n";
    }

      if(abs(int(elem->getValue().size())/elem->getNbAttr()) > max)
      {
        max = int(elem->getValue().size());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "\nsensor not found\n";
    }g, std::unique_ptr<Sensor>, int, std::string>;

  //this file is used to create all the new sensors, the user will only need to modify this one
  inline void initialise(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>>& sensorList)
  {
    //creating a factory element
    using AFactory = FactorySensor<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Sensor>, int, std::string>;
    AFactory factory;

    /*//creating a map to store all the sensors
    std::map<int, Sensor*> sensorList = std::map<int, Sensor*>();*/

    //---to change to a for---
    //this is a pointer to a sensor element, used to move the sensors from the factory to our map
    Sensor* sensor = nullptr;

    //the ksp project uses: 00 time / 01 temperature / 02 pressure / 03 acceleration/ 04 gps/ 05 altitude/ 06 gyroscope

    //i only create one sensor for the tests, but i can create many
    //creating a temperature sensor
    factory.registe("temp_sensor", [](int arg1, std::string arg2) { return std::make_unique<Temperature>(arg1,arg2); });
    std::unique_ptr<Sensor> temperature = factory.create("temp_sensor", 01, "temp");
    sensor = temperature.get();
    sensorList.insert(std::make_pair(sensor->getID(), std::move(temperature)));

    //this part works perfectly, i can see all my sensors, call the methods, no problem
    for (const auto &elem: sensorList)
    {
      std::cout << "depuis sensorinit------je suis une id de sensor " << elem.second->getID() << "\n";
      std::cout << "depuis sensorinit------je suis un nom de sensor " << elem.second->getName() << "\n";
    }
  }

} /* dolmen */

#endif
```

So the problem is: my sensors exists in my map, as long as i am in `initialise()`, but as soon i get out of this function, they suddently disappear.
I tried the code i have in `initialise()` directly inside my `prog.cpp`, everything went well, so the problem only appeared when i tried to delocalise my code.

My theory is: the unique_ptr are disappearing while getting out of my function, but i don't really know if it's this or no, and if it's this, how can i fix this?

Have a nice day

PS: i apologise, english isn't my native language

---

EDIT: now the problem is somewhere else, in a file named dolmen.cpp, in a method named decoding (dolmen is a class)

dolmen.cpp

```cpp
std::string Dolmen::decoding(std::string data, std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>> sensorList)
  {
    //finding the correct sensor in the sensor list by matching the id with the data frame id
    //dolmen::Sensor* elem; --> this is my old version, this worked until my sensor list became to use unique_ptr instead of *
    std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor> elem;
    if (auto it = sensorList.find(id); it != sensorList.end())
    {
      elem = it->second; //the problem is here
    }

    //searching the maximum number of datas returned by the sensor
    //(some sensors can return one value, some can return many values)
    int max = 0;
    if (elem->getID() == id)
    {
      //decoding the data with the correct sensor, to create a map which contain all the datas of the sensor, from our data frame
      elem->decoding(data);

      if(abs(int(elem->getValue().size())/elem->getNbAttr()) > max)
      {
        max = int(elem->getValue().size());
      }
    }
    else
    {
      std::cout << "\nsensor not found\n";
    }
  }
```

The best case scenario is the following: i create my sensorList once, then for each line of data to decode, i call Dolmen::decoding (so unique_ptr will cause some problems...)

Hpw can i solve this?

Comment: Your theory is correct.

Comment: Either don't use unique_ptr, or (probably better) use it consistently, change your map to  `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>>`

Comment: So i'll have: `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>>` instead of `std::map<int, dolmen::Sensor*>`?

Comment: i just tried it... and i got an absolutly messy error message:
```/usr/include/c++/9/ext/new_allocator.h:145:20: error: use of deleted function ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<dolmen::Sensor>]’
  145 |  noexcept(noexcept(::new((void *)__p)
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  146 |        _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)))
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
make: *** [GNUmakefile:209: prog.o] Error 1
```
(i only paste the last part)

Comment: Edit what you tried into question. In comment it is messy. The logic of unique_ptr is that object pointed by it belongs to one thing at any one time.  If it first belongs to initialize() then you have to std::move it to sensorList to make it to belong to sensorList.  That get() does not transfer ownership and so you will have dangling raw pointer in sensorList.

Comment: @ÖöTiib so my `initialise()` function will have to return my map, with a std::move()?

Comment: No. I suggested to edit what you tried into your question. Then I said that your initialize should move its temperature into your sensorList to transfer ownership of it. sensorList.insert(std::make_pair(sensor->getID(), std::move(temperature)));

Comment: @ÖöTiib i changed my code with your suggestion, but still don't work

Comment: It sounds like your pseudocode "[grabbing a sensor in my sensor x list]  x->getID();" does not work. I am not a psychic so I can't tell what in your undisclosed implementation of that pseudocode does not work.

Comment: If i comment my pseudocode part, effectivly, all works well, so the problem seems to have changed, thank you very much, one part seems solved.
Now i need to solve my pseudocode part, which is really different

Comment: BUT... if i use unique_ptr, this totally mess up my code later x)
So i'm stuck
should i upload all my code?

Comment: I added the new problematic code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the `unique_ptr`s in the map, here is a simplified version of what you need to do to get it working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

void initialise(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>& map) {
    for(auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        auto newObject = std::make_unique<int>(i);
        map[i] = std::move(newObject);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> map;
    initialise(map);

    for(const auto& e : map) {
        std::cout << *(e.second) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

you can see it work [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/532e282df294a2aa)

Comment: I tried this, but this don't compile anymore, and i can't understand the error message

Comment: Thank you for the answer, we decided to remove this feature for the moment, then try to automate the factory later if we have time (this is a school project, so we don't have a lot of time)